# Override theme for date field output?

Tags: 7, theming

I have a field that accepts a date range using the Date module.  This is the theme function for outputting the date (found in `sites/all/modules/contrib/date/date.theme`):

```
/**
 * Returns HTML for a date element formatted as a range.
 */
function theme_date_display_range($variables) {
  $date1 = $variables['date1'];
  $date2 = $variables['date2'];
  $timezone = $variables['timezone'];
  $attributes_start = $variables['attributes_start'];
  $attributes_end = $variables['attributes_end'];

  // Wrap the result with the attributes.
  return t('!start-date to !end-date', array(
    '!start-date' => '<span class="date-display-start"' . drupal_attributes($attributes_start) . '>' . $date1 . '</span>',
    '!end-date' => '<span class="date-display-end"' . drupal_attributes($attributes_end) . '>' . $date2 . $timezone . '</span>',
  ));
}
```

I somehow need to override that and replace the 'to' in the return with a hyphen... I know, it's nitpicky but it underlines a more important point - I honestly have no way to alter this.  I've tried overriding it in my `template.php` but that doesn't take.  I literally just copy and pasted this code but replaced `theme` in the function with the actual name for my theme.

So yeah... how do I alter this theme function "the Drupal way"?

Comment: did you try clearing your cache?

Answer (score 3):

With the help of [hook_theme_registry_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7) you can override(actually by passing) any theme function.

Usually module's will define their theme functions in [hook_theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7), however using [hook_theme_registry_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7) you can alter those information.

For your case below code will achieve the desired functionality,

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter().
 */
function <my_module>_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  if (isset($theme_registry['date_display_range'])) {
    $theme_registry['date_display_range']['function'] = 'theme_custom_date_display_range';
  }
}

/**
 * Returns HTML for a date element formatted as a range.
 */
function theme_custom_date_display_range($variables) {
  $date1 = $variables['date1'];
  $date2 = $variables['date2'];
  $timezone = $variables['timezone'];
  $attributes_start = $variables['attributes_start'];
  $attributes_end = $variables['attributes_end'];

  // Wrap the result with the attributes.
  return t('!start-date - !end-date', array(
    '!start-date' => '<span class="date-display-start"' . drupal_attributes($attributes_start) . '>' . $date1 . '</span>',
    '!end-date' => '<span class="date-display-end"' . drupal_attributes($attributes_end) . '>' . $date2 . $timezone . '</span>',
  ));
}
```

So whenever you call **theme('date_display_range', $variables)**, **theme_custom_date_display_range()** function will be invoked instead of **theme_date_display_range()**.

Don't forget to clear the caches after adding [hook_theme_registry_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to change "to" to "-", then hook_theme_alter is overkill.

You can simply use the translation layer:

At least 2 options:

1. in settings.php:

   $conf['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array('!start-date to !end-date' => '!start-date - !end-date');
2. use [stringoverrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module, which provides a GUI for same.